# create generic method in java

Tags: java, generics

If I change `(Inventory)` to `(T)` it does not recognize `getId()`.

```
    public static <T> T getSelectedRow(Table table) {
        T selectedItems = (T) table.getValue();
        if (selectedItems != null) {
            System.out.println("getSelectedRow id:"+ ((Inventory) selectedItems).getId());
            return selectedItems;
        }
```

How can I make it work as `((T) selectedItems).getId()`
Table is vaadin7 and I use java 8.

I do not want to use `Inventory`, it should be generic so I could use different objects. `Inventory` is just one of them, some have `getId()` some not!

Comment: What is wrong if you did `<?  extends Inventory>` for the class?

Comment: I do not want to use Inventory, it should be generic so I could use different objects. Inventory is just one of them, some have getId() some not!

Comment: Then what is stopping you from implementing `<T extends ClassWithGetId>`  and have a method `getId();` overridden in `Inventory.class`

Comment: Not all objects have ``getId();``

Comment: Interfaces have a concept called `default` method.

Comment: Ìt is not just ``getId();`` there are more methods that not all of them all objects have ``getId();``, just ``Inventory`` and some.  Probably can not have multiple default methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed need `getId`:

```
public interface HasId {
    long getId();
}

public class Inventory implements HasId {

    @Override
    public long getId() { return id; }
}

public static <T extends HasId> T getSelectedRow(Table table) {
    T selectedItems = (T) table.getValue();
    if (selectedItems != null) {
        System.out.println("getSelectedRow id:"+ selectedItems.getId());
        return selectedItems;
    }
...
```

Or (without interface) a bit more ugly, breakable - when only `getId` is needed:

```
public static <T> T getSelectedRow(Table table, ToLongFunction<T> idGetter) {
    T selectedItems = (T) table.getValue();
    if (selectedItems != null) {
        System.out.println("getSelectedRow id:"+ idGettter.apply(selectedItems));
        return selectedItems;
    }
...

Inventory inventory = getSelectedRow(table, Inventory::getId);
```

Comment: Note that in your first example, the one using the `HasId` interface, the type parameter `T` adds nothing to the method, by which I mean it doesn't add type safety. They could just cast to `HasId` directly and have the same effect. Your second example is more flexible than the first.

Comment: So second example could work, because I do not want to use Inventory, it should be generic so I could use different objects. Inventory is just one of them, some have getId() some not? And it is not just getId, there are different methods.

Comment: If there are different methods passing them all as method references would be unordered, painfull. You could require an adapter class as parameter, you create for Inventory and other classes.

Comment: @andrej It sounds like you're trying to create a method that can handle any situation. Either all the types are going to need to implement a common interface or you're going to need different methods. I recommend the second option to avoid having one method do too much. Anyway, remember that in Java generics are erased. In other words, generics are a compile-time only mechanism. This is why, for instance, in Joop's first example the type parameter `T` is superfluous. Casting to `T` in that case is exactly the same as casting to `HasId`, due to the upper bound.

Comment: @Slaw that comment shows experience one should heed. Better live with a couple of edited copies, and _than_ replace them with a generic method, as trying a generic method from the outset, that might be too restrictive resp. too widely scoped.

Comment: @Slaw that was my thinking, but I needed confirmation. Thanks. But do not understand what you mean with "type parameter T is superfluous".

Comment: About `T`: one would either expect `Table<T>` or a parameter `Class<T> type` because of type erasure, doing `T t = type.cast(table.getValue())`

Comment: @andrej I mean it's redundant, unneeded, essentially meaningless. This only applies to the first example. No matter what type argument you use, to the method it will always be a `HasId`. Since the `T` is not used as a return type or as one or more parameter types there is nothing being added by the `T`. In the second example, since the `T` is used by the `ToLongFunction` the `T` has meaning. Of course, you still have an unchecked cast problem; that's where using `Class<T>` may come in handy, as shown by Joop's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Because `T` is a placeholder for a type and as far as the compiler is concerned `T` does not have `getId()` or any other methods which are not part of `Object`. You can not do that.

However you could constraint `T` to `<T extends Inventory>`

Comment: I do not want to use Inventory, it should be generic so I could use different objects. Inventory is just one of them, some have getId() some not!